# What is the better way to implement MapView with multiple BottomViews or PullUpControllers?

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns

I am a beginner in developing iOS applications. Working in an application, where I am making all views programmatically.

I want to display a Map along with different bottom views. When first time the view is loaded, it displays Map along with first bottom view. When user performs an action, it displays the second bottom view but with the same Map View.

So in a nutshell I need to keep the same Map view but display several bottom view based on user action. I am looking for a better way to display bottom view based on user action and if user click on back button, it should return to last-displayed bottom view.

- I tried to apply NavigationController on the bottom view controller (which is a child controller to Map View Controller) but it displays the child view in the entire windows instead of displaying in the bottom.
- I also thought of registering bottom views to an event and show/hide bottom view based on what kind of event occurred. But here I also want to keep track of last event so when user clicks on back button it should display the last view. As this is very initial state so don't know if it's a good idea or not.

Answer (score 0):

use a collection view with paging enabled and width of each cell equal to the screen width and scroll to next cell based on user action.